# What is the use of all GET, PUT, DELETE when anything can be done by POST in the most secured way of communication in REST API calls

Tags: function, rest

I read a lot about each and every function of those mentioned in the title,
But I always have doubt that what is the primary use of all individual functions. Can someone explain to me in detail? Thank you.

Comment: The method can be used for internal routing - sort of like a classification system, so all deletes happen in a `DELETE`. That may be useful for the engineer building a RESTful system. Intermediate cache systems can also differentiate between read and write calls too.

Comment: POST isn't ever any more secure then PUT or DELETE. It's not more secure than GET when GET is used properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the use of all GET, PUT, DELETE when anything can be done by POST

This is a pretty important question.

Note that, historically, [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) essentially did everything by POST; effectively reducing HTTP from an application protocol to a transport protocol.

The big advantage of GET/PUT/DELETE is that the additional semantics that they promise (meaning, the semantics that are part of the uniform interface agreed to by *all* resources) allow us to build *general purpose* components that can do interesting things with the meta data alone, without needing to understand anything specific about the body of the message.

The most important of these is `GET`, which promises that the action of the request is safe.  What this means is that, for any resource in the world, we can just try a GET request to "see what happens".

In other words, because GET is safe, we can have web crawlers, and automated document indexing, and eventually Google.

(Another example - today, I can send you a bare URI, like https://www.google.com and it "just works" because GET is understood uniformly, and does not require that we share any further details about a payload or metadata.)

Similarly, PUT and DELETE have additional semantic constraints that allow general purpose components to do interesting things like automatically retry lost requests when the network is unreliable.

POST, however, is effectively unconstrained, and this greatly restricts the actions of general purpose components.

That doesn't mean that POST is [the wrong choice](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post); if the semantics of a request aren't worth standardizing, then POST is *fine*.

Answer (score 1):

In API perspective,

GET - It is to retrieve record/data from a source. API would need no data from client/UI to retrieve all records , or would need query param / path param to filter records based on what is required - either record with a particular ID or other properties.

POST - it is to store a new record  at a source . API would get that record from client/UI through request body and store it.

PUT - it is to update an existing record at a source . API would receive updated record along with Id and update it with existing record whose id match with one passed from UI.

DELETE - it is to delete a record present in source. UI would send nothing to delete whole all records at source or send id to remove a particular record.

Source refers to any database.